# Multiple controls with the same ID “controlID” were found but does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls

I'm getting the dreaded error:

**Multiple controls with the same ID “lblEnteredBy” were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs**

Here's the problem, the ID "**lblEnteredBy**" is no where in .cs, .aspx, .css, .js, etc., or my entire Project or Solution, let alone the page.
I've checked all the auto-created javascripts Microsoft created; nothing.  It is not auto-generated or pulled as a control ID from databases (*just in case someone asks...*) wherein a control ID is then set (*and, yeah, I've seen this method used; it was ugly...*)

I have absolutely no idea where it is coming from or how it gets on the page.

I cannot replicated it on my **DEV** or **TEST** boxes. Only occurs in **PROD**uction.

Insights appreciated.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

Try these out
1. Perform a 'Find' operation in your entire solution.
2. If that persists, place some breakpoints in your methods and view the container collection which holds all the controls which the replica is showing up.